# R convert string "Jan\n1990" to date format

Tags: r, datetime

I have a csv file with the first column (named "month") having month data in the format
"Jan\n1990", "Feb\n1990" and so on.
When I read the file in R using read.csv function (with stringsAsFactors = FALSE) it reads the "month" column as 'chr'. I want to convert it into date format. I tried

```
month_1 <- as.Date(f4$month)
```

But it gives the error

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

How do I convert the first column into a date formatted column?

Comment: Dates require days... So you will have to provide this along with the current variable. Use `paste(..., collapse="...")` and work out the needed formatting from `?strftime`.

Comment: And yes, this is definitely something you can do in Python. See the `datetime` module.

Answer (score 2):

In `r`, using the function `parse_date_time` from `lubridate` package, you can convert your character string into a date format:

```r
date <- c("Jan\n1990","Feb\n1990") # Example of character strings to convert into dates

library(lubridate)
parse_date_time(date, order = "bY")

[1] "1990-01-01 UTC" "1990-02-01 UTC"
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution based on `as.Date`:

```
date <- c("Jan\n1990","Feb\n1990") 

as.Date(paste0("1",date), format="%d%b\n%Y")
# [1] "1990-01-01" "1990-02-01"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `as.yearmon` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
as.Date(as.yearmon(date))
#[1] "1990-01-01" "1990-02-01"
```